# Ragnarok Online crashes in Ubuntu 12.10 (evolution-calendar-factory crashed)

Tags: updates, wine, games, bug-reporting

I just recently updated my operating system from 12.04 to 12.10 and when I try to run Ragnarok Online through Wine as I usually do, though it goes well for a while, after a few minutes my computer crashes completely and I've got to un-plug the PC to restore it. After rebooting I get a report stating that `ExecutablePath /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory` crashed. Any idea what's might be my problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server/+bug/1062068